# how to filter address according country and city in google maps autocomplete address api

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How to filter address  according country and city in  google maps autocomplete address api.
i am able to address filter according country but i am not able to address filter according country and city. I am using following code:-

```
 var autocompleteFrom;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var options = {
            types: ['geocode'],
            componentRestrictions: { country: "IL" }
        };
        var inputFrom = document.getElementById('Address');
        autocompleteFrom = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(inputFrom, options);
        google.maps.event.addListener(autocompleteFrom, 'place_changed', fillAddrss);
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to apply a city filter in place autocomplete at the moment.

There is a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35822067) in Google issue tracker to make this happen. However we cannot see any ETA there.

I can suggest staring the feature request to add your vote and receive updates from Google.

As a workaround you can define city bounds and filter results by city bounds applying a strictBounds parameter

```
var options = {
    bounds: cityBounds,
    strictBounds: true,
    types: ['geocode'],
    componentRestrictions: { country: "IL" }
};
```

Please refer to docs for further details:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#AutocompleteOptions