# Restricting autocomplete search to particular region (google places)

Tags: react-native, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I want to restrict my search only for the places within my city, any help would be highly appreciated

I'm using => FaridSafi/react-native-google-places-autocomplete

Thanks

Comment: There is no component filter for city. As a workaround you should use location, radius and strictbounds parameters. Have a look at documenation https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete

Comment: Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42810524/how-to-filter-address-according-country-and-city-in-google-maps-autocomplete-add

Comment: thanks I got it working by adding parameter correctly in query string.

Anyway thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your code

```
query={{
                    // available options: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete
                    key: "API KEY",
                    language: "en", // language of the results
                    location: "-33.865143, 151.209900",
                    radius: "100000", //100 km
                    components: "country:au", // country name
                    strictbounds: true,
                  }}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
      ref={ref}
      currentLocation={true}
      placeholder="Enter Location"
      minLength={2}
      autoFocus={false}
      returnKeyType={'default'}
      placeholderTextColor="black"
      fetchDetails={true}
      enablePoweredByContainer={false}
      query={{
        key: 'Your API key',
        language: 'en',
        types: '(cities)', <=== use this to only show country cities
        components: 'country:pk', , <=== use this to restrict to country
      }}
    
      filterReverseGeocodingByTypes={[
        'locality',
        'administrative_area_level_1',
      ]}
      GooglePlacesSearchQuery={{
        rankby: 'distance',
      }}
      nearbyPlacesAPI="GooglePlacesSearch"
      styles={{
        textInputContainer: styles.textInputContainer,
        description: {
          fontWeight: 'bold',
        },
        textInput: styles.textInputAutoPlace,
      }}
    />
```