# Google API Places - Address suggest from a city

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I tried to find a solution only for this issue without success. So i will appreciate your help.

I would like to get autocomplete address from google api. I'm using this code now:

```
var input, options, zip;
$( document ).ready(function() {
    options = {
        types: ['address'],
        componentRestrictions: {
            'country': 'IT'
        }
    };
    zip = $('#residence_zip');
    input = document.getElementById('autocomplete');
    initAutocomplete();
});

function initAutocomplete() {
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function () {
        var element = $(autocomplete.getPlace().adr_address);
        var cap = jQuery(element[2]).text();
        zip.val(cap);
    });
}
```

It works well! but i would like to add a filter by city name. I'm trying like this:

```
options = {
        types: ['address'],
        componentRestrictions: {
            'country': 'IT', 'locality': 'Roma'
        }
    };
```

But it doesn't work. :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42810524/how-to-filter-address-according-country-and-city-in-google-maps-autocomplete-add

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to filter Place Autocomplete predictions to one specific city only. At this time `componentRestrictions` can only be used to filter Autocomplete results by country.

Take a look at [this open feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35822067) in Google's Issue Tracker which I suggest starring to increase visibility and subscribe to future updates.

As a potential workaround you can try [filtering results by the bounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#set_search_area) that define the city of Roma. Also see related [How to restrict google places to specific city](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33214788/how-to-restrict-google-places-to-specific-city)

Hope this helps!